# Error 500: org/unbescape/html/HtmlEscape - When trying to reach endpoints (using thymeleaf templates)

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on a Spring boot 2.1.1 project in Maven 4. I'm facing 
`Error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500) org/unbescape/html/HtmlEscape` when I'm trying to reach any endpoint defined in my controller. I have thymeleaf as templating engine.

pom.xml Thymeleaf dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Logs from eclipse console when I try to reach "/" (happens at any endpoint):

```
INFO 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 17 ms
ERROR 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/unbescape/html/HtmlEscape] with root cause`

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.unbescape.html.HtmlEscape

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.EscapedAttributeUtils.unescapeAttribute(EscapedAttributeUtils.java:103) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:72) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

And the list goes on. I am seeking for your help, thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that your application is requiring unbescape.  You can add try adding this to your pom.xml: `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.unbescape/unbescape -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unbescape</groupId>
    <artifactId>unbescape</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: It worked out. Thank you, appreciated.